# Change URL name with mod rewrite on htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a tough time to understand how mod_rewrite works.

I have a url like this:

> www.example.com/store/index.php?categ=headbands

And I want to make it look like this:

> www.example.com/store/headbands

I am trying this, but not working:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /store/
RewriteRule ^index/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1  [L]
```

And I confirmed the mod_rewrite is activated with a random example I found.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: If you wanna match against a leading `store`, why does your second rule say `index`? And why does it rewrite to `$1` instead of `index.php?categ=...`?

Comment: I would think that since RewriteBase already takes me to the `/store/` location, then I need to specify the next reference...

Comment: Don't utilize [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) for such simple structures. It's for more odd cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^/store/(.*)$ /store/index.php?categ=$1 [NC,L]
```

**OR** 
Put the .htaccess file inside the "store" directory with following code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?categ=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Place the .htaccess file inside the store directory and replace the last line of code with this one `RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?categ=$1 [NL,C]`. I hope this will work.

Comment: wow, this really didnt work: Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Oh! My mistake `[NL,C]` causes that error . 100% sure now it'll be fixed. replace that with `[NC,L]`. Good Luck.

Comment: visit this url : http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ . It is helpful for the beginners on url rewriting like you and me.